# Spatial and time lag autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, spatio-temporal

I am designing an experiment to examine spatial autocorrelation within 50km of a point. The setting is the open ocean with sensors that take depth profiles of environmental data (Temperature, Salinity, Oxygen, etc.). One instrument will remain at a fixed point. The second instrument will collect observations for 24 hours, and then move 3 km away. These 3km steps with 24 hour sampling will continue over a month.

It not possible to take all these measurements in space on the same day. How do I account for spatial autocorrelation if the observations have a time lag as well? Is there a version of Moran's I for autocorrelation that would take into account the time lag of 1 day between observations. The purpose is to examine how representative a single point is within a particular radius in this ocean region.

Comment: This is a complicated setting that requires more details to be answerable.  There is some literature on geostatistical sampling designs.  The insight it offers is that you want to have clusters of closely-spaced measurements so that you have a relatively large number of samples at short lags, where it is important to estimate the covariogram (or semivariance, or one of their robust analogs) as accurately as possible.  How exactly to do that depends on how you intend to use the autocorrelation information and on what assumptions you make or previous information you have.

Comment: Are the observations already sampled? Do you have active control of the moving sensors, ore are they drifting more or less slowly? Do you have some prior information on how fast the parameters you measure might change with time? ...